# VBA - proper name management in libraries

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA .xla file containing

- one main module with the main interface, e.g. `readDiagram()`
- approx 10 modules which provide the functionality implementation to `readDiagram()`. As I do not like modules having thousands of lines, I decided to separate the interface from the implementation.

In order to make the interface function see the implementation, the implementation functions have to be declared as `public`. However, that implies that upon referencing the .xla in another project, all the implementation functions can be seen from that project, which is undesirable. Is there a way to separate a .xla into more modules and at the same time make only one function of the whole .xla visible to the outside world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all the implementation Subs, put this as the fisrt line

```
Option Private Module
```

Comment: + 1 Good One. Nice and Simple. I thought I had typed a message.